# RStudio session aborts when I run gRbase::stepwise function (undirected graphs)

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, abort

I'm doing an R project on RStudio (RStudio 2021.09.1+372 "Ghost Orchid" Release for Windows), (R version 4.1.2).
I'm working on Windows 10 x64.

I want to create an Undirected Graph from a dataset:

```
library(gRbase)
library(gRim)
library(gRain)
data(BodyFat)
BodyFat <- BodyFat[-c(31,42,48,76,86,96,159,169,175,182,206),]
BodyFat$Age <- sqrt(BodyFat$Age)
BodyFat$Weight <- sqrt(BodyFat$Weight)
names(BodyFat)[names(BodyFat) == 'BodyFat'] <- 'BodyFatPerc'
gRbodyfat <- BodyFat[,2:15]
graph.MyGraph <- cmod(~.^., data = gRbodyfat)
AIC.MyGraph <- gRbase::stepwise(graph.MyGraph)
```

I'm still exploring RStudio and graphical models, so I run these lines from the console, one by one.
When I run the **last** line of code, R session aborts and I get the following pop-up message:

[image: Session Aborted]

I've also tried the following lines of code (I changed the last line):

```
library(gRbase)
library(gRim)
library(gRain)
data(BodyFat)
BodyFat <- BodyFat[-c(31,42,48,76,86,96,159,169,175,182,206),]
BodyFat$Age <- sqrt(BodyFat$Age)
BodyFat$Weight <- sqrt(BodyFat$Weight)
names(BodyFat)[names(BodyFat) == 'BodyFat'] <- 'BodyFatPerc'
gRbodyfat <- BodyFat[,2:15]
graph.MyGraph <- cmod(~.^., data = gRbodyfat)    
AIC.MyGraph <- stepwise(graph.MyGraph)
```

but I get the same problem. I tried three or four times running those lines of code, R aborted everytime.

My gRbase, gRim, gRain, Rgraphviz and RBGL libraries are in the home folder:

```
C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
```

Any advice?

EDIT:

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling R, Rtools, RStudio, reinstalling libraries, updating them, I've tried launching RStudio as Administrator, I've tried changing computer.

The last thing I tried is this:

1. uninstalling R, Rtools and RStudio
2. deleting .RData and .Renviron files in the Documents folder
3. deleting all libraries
4. downloading R (latest version) from CRAN webpage and installing it as Administrator
5. downloading Rtools (latest version from webpage) and installing it as Administrator
6. creating the .Renviron file as described [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html)
7. downloading RStudio (latest version from webpage) and installing it as Administrator
8. installing BiocManager as described [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/install) (when asked to update Matrix library I said NO, I thought it could be the problem)
9. installing gRbase, gRim, gRain libraries as described [here](https://people.math.aau.dk/%7Esorenh/software/gR/) (when asked to update fansi library I said NO because it said "There are binary versions available but the source versions are later", I thought it could be the problem)
10. Tried again the lines of code

Still got the problem, R session aborted again.

A friend of mine doing a similar project used gRbase::stepwise function, so I inserted his code in the console and the function worked. So I think the problem might be the object of the function, graph.MyGraph. The cmod function works fine, so maybe there's a problem with gRbodyfat, which is used to build graph.MyGraph.

If I run these lines (I tried changing the dataset, I used BodyFat instead of gRbodyfat):

```
graph.MyGraph <- cmod(~.^., data = BodyFat)
AIC.MyGraph <- gRbase::stepwise(graph.MyGraph)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in dim(res) <- c(NSEL, NSET) : 
dims [product 210] do not match the length of object [14]
```

Don't know what to do.

EDIT:

I've tried debugging gRbase::stepwise function and I get this:

[image: iModel function]

The problem appears to be the iModel function.

EDIT:

I've discovered that if I use `graph.MyGraph <- cmod(~.^1, data = gRbodyfat)` the `gRbase::stepwise` function works fine.

Comment: Try running your code in R directly (i.e. without using R Studio) to see if the problem still occurs. That at least narrows down whether the IDE is involved in the issue, or if the problem is 1. R itself, or 2. the packages you're using.

Comment: @Phil - I tried using the RGUI, i.e. opening the R executable directly. The last line of code made the GUI crash. Don't know what to do. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the gRbase library but it didn't work.

Comment: I would file a bug report to the makers of the gRbase and/or gRim packages. It seems to me that there is an issue with their setup of the `stepwise()` function leading to the crash.

Comment: @Phil - Could you link me an article to learn how to do that?

Comment: @Phil - Some friends doing the same project didn't find any bug. The stepwise function went fine for them, even if they used the same R version and same RStudio version

Comment: @Phil - Also, after writing the lines of code in the console I wrote them in a .R file inside RStudio, so as to create a script which would make things easier. I discovered by chance that if I press the "Source" button on the upper right of the file window R session aborts again: it starts loading packages (graph, BiocGenerics, parallel, grid) and when it loads the "grid" package R session aborts. Don't know why.

Comment: I'd mention this to the package author, contact info is here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRim/index.html This could be an issue related to the chip processor.

Comment: @Phil - Thanks. Would you mind checking my edits? I've discovered some stuff.

Comment: Again, something to send to the package maintainer.